# Using applescript to open url in existing chrome tab?

Tags: google-chrome, scripting, applescript

I have a simple applescript that I launch at the beginning of class every day to set up my development environment and open my directory in Chrome. It works as it, but I am OCD and would like it to open the URL in the existing new tab that is created when you first launch Chrome.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    open location "http://mydir.dev"
end tell
```

I've tried searching through the Chrome dictionary but I can't seem to find anything to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    set URL of active tab of window 1 to "http://mydir.dev"
end tell
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this need to then refresh the page